# How to prevent receive socket from blocking forever in case it receives no data?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, system-calls, blocking

In case of a blocking UDP socket `blocking on receive` does not receive any data, and is not going to receive any data because the sender process has crashed for some reason.
The socket option `SO_RCVTIMEO` could be set to make sure the receive system call is going to return, but is there a "known approach" to solve that problem(since the value of the timeout is not precise and depends on the system if it is slow or not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) function to know a something is ready to be read on a socket.

```
while (1)
{
    int retval;
    fd_set rfds;
    // one second timeout
    struct timeval tv = {1,0};

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd, &rfds);

    retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    if (retval == -1)
    {
        perror("select()");
        exit(1);
    }        
    else if (retval)
    {
        printf("Data is available now.\n"); 
        // if recvfrom() is called here, it won't block
    }
    else
    {
        // no data to read... perform other tasks
    }
}
```